# While Deserializing Ambigous match found error is showing

Tags: json

```
"[
{\"CHECK\":false,\"PRODUCTID\":\"272\",\"PURPRODUCT\":null,\"PURCHASEID\":\"103\",\"PURCHASEDETAILID\":\"92\",\"PARTNERID\":null,\"UNSTOCKID\":null,\"CURRID\":null,\"ITEMNAME\":\"\",\"DESCRIPTION\":null,\"PRODUCTCODE\":\"\",\"VENDORPRODUCTCODE\":\"\",\"QUANTITY\":\"1\",\"PURQUANTITY\":null,\"AVAILABLEQUANTITY\":null,\"UNITPRICE\":45,\"DISCOUNT\":\"0.000\",\"ORDER\":null,\"ORDERDATE\":null,\"STATUS\":null,\"INVENTORYSTATUS\":null,\"PAYMENTSTATUS\":null,\"VENDOR\":null,\"VENDORORDER\":null,\"LOCATION\":null,\"REQUESTEDSHIPDATE\":null,\"REMARKS\":null,\"DUEDATE\":null,\"TOTALAMT\":0,\"PAID\":0,\"BALANCE\":0,\"RECIEVEDATE\":null,\"RETURNDATE\":null,\"UNSTOCKDATE\":null,\"SUBTOTAL\":\"45.000\",\"SUPPLIERORDERNUMBER\":null,\"UNITPRICEFC\":null,\"EXCHANGERATE\":null,\"PORETURNID\":null,\"ORDERNUMBER\":null,\"PAYMENT\":null,\"PAY\":null,\"PORECIEVEID\":null,\"PRODUCTDETAILID\":\"80\",\"BRANCHID\":null,\"UOM\":null,\"MASTERID\":null,\"RECEIVEDQTY\":null,\"AVAILABLEQTY\":null,\"ISRECEIVED\":null,\"MovedToScrap\":null,\"DisposalPrice\":null,\"RQUANTITY\":null,\"RETURNQUANTITY\":null,\"PURCHASEID_FK\":null,\"UNSTOCKQUANTITY\":null,\"TOTALINQTY\":null,\"TOTALOUTQTY\":null,\"AVLQTY\":null,\"MOVETOSCRAP\":null,\"DISPOSALPRICE\":null,\"DATE\":null,\"STATUSID\":null}

]"
```

Above is the json i am getting i am trying to deserializing it with below code

```
 foreach (JProperty content in jsonResponse.Children())
 {
     if (content.Name == "prdata")
     {
         Val = content.Value.ToString();
         lstProductData = jserial.Deserialize<List<Models.Data.Purchase>>(Val);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two `DisposalPrice` which might be causing this issue while deserializing